# Silverlight application not bring data through Wcf service on dropbox

Tags: silverlight, dropbox

I have created a silverlight application and my db is on some host, I have connected my db to silverlight application through wcf service, it runs well on my pc, and bring data from db. But when I host it on dropbox public folder, it runs but db data not coming. i have

Comment: You have.... an incomplete question.  When you say 'db data not coming', do you get an error message, or does your Silverlight application act as if all of the database tables were empty?  Does your service have a [`clientaccesspolicy.xml` or `crossdomain.xml` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx)?

Comment: Yes i am using mysql and my db is hosted on server, so i am using this connection string ( String con_emp = "server=166.78.1.235;uid=tahiraslam;pwd=tahir12345;database=tahir_db;"; ) so when i run my silverlight application on my Pc the data is comming but when i host my code on dropbox data is not coimng, – TAHIR ASLAM yesterday

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a connection string problem with this scenario. I typically use the default one from the designer for the `localhost` and then when I publish I use the connection string for the `server`. Since you have not given us a DB type or server type here is a universal connection builder site.

[ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.connectionstrings.com%2F&ei=7BEkUuGPGsaA2QWojoCQBQ&usg=AFQjCNFp35VmkJSg5VOClxRITQ5sJhjCbQ&sig2=ukKepiB5eUfubKV9Uz1jqg&bvm=bv.51495398,d.b2I)

Comment: Yes i am using mysql and my db is hosted on server, so i am using this connection string (  String con_emp = "server=166.78.1.235;uid=tahiraslam;pwd=tahir12345;database=tahir_db;"; ) so when i run my silverlight application on my Pc the data is comming  but when i host my code on silverlight data is not coimng,